# Issue with: Missing required parameters for [Route: ]

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-8

I'm getting super confused, but I expect it is a really simple mistake on my part.

When visiting `/admin/service`, this exception is thrown:

> Missing required parameters for [Route: admin.service.toggle.isFeatured] [URI: admin/service/toggle/isFeatured/{service}/{status}]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\resources\views\admin\service\index.blade.php)

**Controller:** AdminServiceController.php

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
      $data = $this->_validate($request);
      $data['creator_id'] = auth()->user()->id;
      Services::create($data);
      return redirect(route("admin.service.index"))->withSuccess("Die neue Leistung wurde hinzugefügt.");
    }

    public function toggleIsFeatured(Services $service,$status)
    {
      $service->update(["is_featured" => !$status]);
      redirect(back()->withSuccess('Status wurde erfolgreich geändert.'));
    }

    public function toggleIsActive(Services $service,$status)
    {
      $service->update(["is_active" => !$status]);
      redirect(back()->withSuccess('Status wurde erfolgreich geändert.'));
    }

    private function _validate($request) {
      $rules = [
        'title' => 'required|unique:services',
        'description' => 'required|min:100',
      ];
      return $this->validate($request, $rules);
    }
```

**View:** index.blade.php

```
<a href="{{route('admin.service.toggle.isFeatured',[$service->id,$service->isFeatured])}}" class="btn btn-info btn-circle btn-sm"> @if($service->is_featured)<i class="fas fa-fw fa-star text-warning"></i> @else <i class="far fa-fw fa-star"></i> @endif</a>

<a href="{{route('admin.service.toggle.isActive',[$service->id,$service->isActive])}}" class="btn btn-info btn-circle btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-circle @if($service->is_active) text-success @else text-danger @endif "></i></a>
```

**Route:** web.php

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function ()
 {
   Route::name('admin.')->group(function () {
     Route::middleware('auth')->group(function ()
     {
       Route::get('/', function ()
       {
        return view('admin');
        });
      Route::resource('service', 'App\Http\Controllers\AdminServiceController');
      Route::get('service/toggle/isFeatured/{service}/{status}', [App\Http\Controllers\AdminServiceController::class, 'toggleIsFeatured'])->name('service.toggle.isFeatured');
      Route::get('service/toggle/isActive/{service}/{status}', [App\Http\Controllers\AdminServiceController::class, 'toggleIsActive'])->name('service.toggle.isActive');
  });
  });
});
```

Comment: you should be passing these parameters as an associative array to the route helper, `['service' => ..., 'status' => ...]` and these parameters can not be `null`

Comment: Try to pass the value to anchor like this  `{{ route('admin.service.toggle.isFeatured',['service' => $service->id,'status' => $service->isFeatured]) }}`

Comment: @WaytoDeveloper same issue: Missing required parameters

Comment: @lagbox same issue :(

Comment: try to declare your route like this `'Route::get('service/toggle/isFeatured/{service}/{status}','AdminServiceController@toggleIsFeatured')->name('service.toggle.isFeatured');`

Comment: @lagbox it's the simple way to declare route rather than use unnecessary things :-(

Comment: Thank you, guys, it works now like a charm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably should be passing the parameters as an associative array to the `route` helper. Though the real issue is something you are trying to pass is a `null`.

Considering your query to update "is featured" is using the field `is_featured` you are using the wrong attribute when trying to access this on the Model, `isFeatured`, which doesn't exist so returns `null`.

```
route('admin.service.toggle.isFeatured', [
    'service' => $service->id,
    'status' => (int) $service->is_featured,
])
```

I have this casting the potential boolean to an integer so there will be something to actually put into the URL at that segment, `0` or `1`. Otherwise `false` will be an empty string, `''`.

This is the same problem for your "is active" stuff. Using the wrong attribute on the model.